# Remove object from list concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I want to remove an object from a list, but I have a thread that is consistently checking the same list using an iterator. I already have the object that I want to remove, do I have to use another iterator to loop through the list, while checking for the object, then deleting it using the iterator or is there a simpler way of doing so? Right now, if I try and remove the object from the list using the remove method, the iterator on the thread gives me a `NoSuchElementException`.

```
//Threaded loop.
Iterator<Client> playersIterator = getPlayers().iterator();
while(playersIterator.hasNext()){
    Client c = playersIterator.next(); //NoSuchElementException
    if(c.getSocket().isClosed()) {
        playersIterator.remove();
        if(getHost() == c) {
            assignNewHost();
        }
        getServer().getLobbyHandler().updateGames();
    }
}


//Use an iterator to remove?
public void removePlayerFromGame(Client client) {
    Game g = getServer().getGame(client);
    if(g != null) {
       g.getPlayers().remove(client);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be best if you used a `synchronized` block so that you can control access to the collection, So essentially, the `removePlayerFromGame` would wait for the iterator to finish before removing, or else, the iterator would wait for the removal to be complete prior to removing. As is, you have no control over what happens when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `synchronized` to control the access to the resources...

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

```
synchronized {
     // your code will wait before removing the object
     g.getPlayers().remove(client);
}
```

Comment: Synchronized on which monitor?

Answer (score 0):

An `Iterator` simply implements traversal. If you remove elements from the list while you are iterating it, the `next` method can throw `NoSuchElementException` even if `hasNext` returned `true`. Adding another iterator won't solve the problem. You will still be deleting things at the same time you are going through them.

What is the outcome you wish to achieve? Do you want `removePlayerFromGame` to wait until the loop finishes executing? In that case, you will need to synchronize access:

```
Collection<Client> players = getPlayers();
synchronized(players) {
    Iterator<Client> playersIterator = getPlayers().iterator();
    // Iterator is safe from deletion
}

Collection<Client> players = getPlayers();
synchronized(players) {
    // Delete when it is safe to do so
    g.getPlayers().remove(client);
}
```

Comment: It will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, not `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: @AndyTurner, break out of the loop if you remove an item and re-init the Iterator.

Comment: @DV88 what if it's not you removing the item, i.e. it is some other thread?

Comment: @AndyTurner Only if the collection implements `modCount`. Which collection type is being used is not mentioned. The only information available in the question is that `next` throws `NoSuchElementException`, yet `hasNext` returned `true`.

Comment: The example you showed has a "remove" which is what I was referencing; in general if you are iterating this list, as @sh0rug0ru says, control access to it with synchronized. eg, call the class that is holding the list for access. Obv if you take that step, you will want to make sure the synchronized code is as efficient as possible. .... I have this pattern all the time where I add to a queue from various external classes and then loop in a thread and remove from that queue to process the requests. And the threaded class is the owner of the queue.

Comment: @AndyTurner, would your problem be solved if your removePlayerFromGame() method instead called the class that had the players list and said : removePlayer(Client client); Then the class with the master list could control access.

Comment: "would your problem be solved if your removePlayerFromGame() method instead called the class that had the players list" *This isn't my problem*.

Comment: Are the code snippets you show in the same class, two different classes, etc? Do either of those code snippets have master control of the list or is it in another class?

Comment: They refer to the corresponding lines in the question code. Presumably, the collections referred in each method refer to the same collection, but if the methods belong in the same class I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the object, you can simply mark it for deletion, and actually remove in the parallel thread

```
while(playersIterator.hasNext()){
    Client c = playersIterator.next(); //NoSuchElementException
    if (c.isMarked) {
        playersIterator.remove();
    } else if(c.getSocket().isClosed()) {
        ...
```

where `isMarked` is

```
volatile boolean isMarked=false;
```

and to mark an object for deletion, one can simply set `isMarked` to `true`, without any synchronization.

Comment: Thanks but the application I'm working on doesn't require responsive speeds and I access the ArrayList many times. To use a boolean for each method would be messy. Syncing the methods worked perfectly.